# Order By TableName and columnname

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets say I have a table with following columns:

```
Id,TableName,Columnname
```

Normally If I would like to do a select with ordering on **TableName** Primary and **ColumnName** secondary I would do

```
Select * From MyTable Order By TableName,ColumnName
```

Now say I would like a special case of ordering depending on TableName

```
Select * From MyTable Order By Case
When TableName = 'Foo' Then '1'
When TableName = 'Bar' Then '2'
When TableName = 'Test' Then '3'
ELSE 1000 END;
```

How do I combine the second alternative with the first alternative, that is special ordering on first TableName and then order the Columnnames with that TableName?

I'm running Microsoft SQL

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add some sample table data and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add column in order list, like any other `ORDER BY` :)

```
Select * From MyTable Order By Case
When TableName = 'Foo' Then '1'
When TableName = 'Bar' Then '2'
When TableName = 'Test' Then '3'
ELSE 1000 END, ColumnName;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `case` method is fine.  I would often use this short-cut:

```
Select *
From MyTable
Order By charindex(TableName, ',Test,Bar,Foo,') desc
```

This is a wee bit arcane.  `charindex()` returns the position of the name in the string.  So, this form will not work for all string values, but it can be generalized:

```
Order By charindex(',' + TableName + ',', ',Test,Bar,Foo,') desc
```

The reversal of the list is to handle missing values.  These are assigned a value of 0, so by putting the values in reverse order, the missing ones come last.  Note that if I know all the values, then I would write this as:

```
Order By charindex(TableName, ',Foo,Bar,Test,') asc
```

Answer (score 0):

As alternative, you could

1) create a new table

```
CREATE TABLE_ORDER (TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, ORDER_VAL INT);
ALTER TABLE TABLE_ORDER ADD CONSTRAINT TABLE_ORDER_PK PRIMARY KEY(TABLE_NAME);
```

2) insert into it appropriate values:

```
 INSERT INTO TABLE_ORDER (TABLE_NAME, ORDER_VAL) VALUES ('Foo', 1);
 INSERT INTO TABLE_ORDER (TABLE_NAME, ORDER_VAL) VALUES ('Bar', 2);
 INSERT INTO TABLE_ORDER (TABLE_NAME, ORDER_VAL) VALUES ('Test', 3);
```

3) Use the following query

```
   SELECT A.* 
   FROM MYTABLE A
   LEFT JOIN TABLE_ORDER B ON A.TABLENAME= B.TABLE_NAME
   ORDER BY B.ORDER_VAL, A.COLUMNNAME
```